# Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-R

Tags: android, flutter

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-P

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.5.25'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please put this code at the end of  **android/build.gradle**  Hopefully, it solves your issue.

```
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"

    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')

    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android") && project.property("android").compileSdkVersion.equals("android-R")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```